# Ruby float with lots of decimals, why?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Why is the following operation leading me to this value:

```
14.99 + 1.5 = 16.490000000000002
```

I would expect it to be 16.49.  How can I avoid those extra decimals?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's how [floating point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) works. If you want a rounded number that's still a `Float` object, you can do

```
result.round(2) #=> 16.49
```

or if you just need a string:

```
"%0.2f" % result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to Ruby, but because of the way floating point numbers are represented in a computer (according to the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard).

In short, some floating point numbers just can't be represented exactly in a computer. If you need better precision, you can try the [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class.